# Detecting seasonality with only one full period of data

Tags: r, seasonality

I have data of the sales of one article in the 53 weeks of 2015 (just 2015) in one shop.

I want to study the seasonality of this article.

I am having problems with my code in R when I try to use `stl` and `decompose` functions, as you can see below:

```
stcf=ts(tcf$tc.Ventas,start=c(2015,1),frequency = 365.25/7)
modelstl<-stl(log(stcf),s.window="periodic")
**Error in stl(stcf, s.window = "periodic") : 
  series is not periodic or has less than two periods**
stcfComp <- decompose(stcf)
**Error in decompose(stcf) : time series has no or less than 2 periods**
```

Is this problem due to stl and decompose functions work with 2 years data or more? If so, how can I study the seasonality of this article with just one year data of its sales?

Comment: I think that there is a statistical question here if you strip away the discussion of R functions. If you could rewrite your question to focus just on how to analyze one year of time series data, I think you will get some helpful answers (and mitigate the risk that the question is closed as being too focused on programming!).

Comment: Thank you for you answer. If I write the ts function with frequency=7, it divides my 53 data in 8 years: from 2015 to 2022. And it is not my case: I have 53 data in one year. And I want to detect its seasonality.

Answer (score 3):

You gave 365.25/7 as the frequency. This results in a frequency of a little over 52 and you have 53 observations. Maybe you intended to give it a frequency of 4?

Consider this logically, you are trying to estimate a repeating pattern but only gave the function a single observation of this repeatable pattern. This is like if I told you to complete the following sequence: 2,?

What is after 2?

The only information you have is 2. You have nothing to go off. It could be arithmetic, geometric, random, etc. There is no way of knowing this with a single observation. Having 53 weeks and using a period of 52 is similar to this.

Try this:

```
stcf=ts(tcf$tc.Ventas,start=c(2015,1),frequency = 4)
```

`modelstl<-stl(log(stcf),s.window="periodic")`

This will allow you to study what happens month to month (approximately). Given your data, you can't study what happens from year to year as you have no baseline to go off.

Comment: I edited the seasonality number from 7 to 4 as I just realized you have 53 observations as in 53 data points and not 53 sets of weekly data.

Comment: Quite a lucid argumentation. Enjoyable! (Although I am not sure if taking a 4-week period makes sense; it might depend on the application.)